# why can't add links to navigation bar when using sticky navigation bar

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm making a blog web site using django and I add a sticky navigation bar to web site and also it work pretty well but I want add links to menu in the navigation bar.I can't do it because there already link in href.I want to keep this link in href because it make navigation bar sticky.I make this sticky navigation bar with help of [w3 school website][1].here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dinindu Theekshana</title>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
      }

    .shadow{
           box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
       }
      .btn-danger {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #f00000;
        border-color: #dc281e;
      }
     
     .masthead {
              background:#3398E1;
              height: auto;
              padding-bottom: 15px;
              box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
              padding-top: 10px;
    }
      #navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        }
        #navbar {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
          color: #333;
          z-index: 9999999;
        }
        #navbar a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }

        #navbar a.active {
          background-color: #294bc5;
          color: white;
        }

        .content {
          padding: 16px;
          padding-top: 50px;
        }

        .sticky {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
        }

        .sticky + .content {
          padding-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Nav bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light shadow" id="mainNav">
      <div id="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <script>
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
      var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

      function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
          navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
          navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }
      </script>
    </nav>
            {% block content %} 
          <!-- Content Goes here -->
            {% endblock content %}
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-3 bg-grey">
              <p class="m-0 text-dark text-center ">Copyright &copy; Dinindu Theekshana</p>
    </footer>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate a little on your problem. And what type of links do you want?

Comment: Replace `href="javascript:void(0)"` with the link you want. What this `javascript:void(0)` does is, it returns `undefined`. It actually prevents the page from refreshing when you click the link and mostly used for demo sites. In your case, w3schools just provided a demo you just copied.

Answer (score 2):

see below example

app/urls.py

```
(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
...
```

in HTML template

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `href="javascript:void(0)"` with the link you want.Because it's just copy and paste from that article [w3 school web site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp) and inside href in this thing is doesn't make any sense. so you can add your own link